# How can I use socketpair to have two way communication between applications?

Tags: linux, socket

How can I use socketpair (C++ Linux) to have two way communication between (two) applications?
Both applications will run on same hardware, hence I am looking for implementation of socketpair on same platform.

I have a simple test program which "connects two sockets" and passes the data between them.

How **do I make them aware that each socket** is in DIFFERENT application?

I have some success doing same task using bluetooth (apps run on different hardware), now I would like to apply similar approach on same hardware.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Include what you have tried, and what went, wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this call. Then you will have a few choices (there may be others):

- Call fork, so that you have two processes with the sockets. Then you can have one end used by the parent, and one by the child.
- Alternatively use a named socket. Then one end is owed by the creator, and the other is attached to a file-name.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I am currently running the primary application (client) communication to the secondary (server). In server I  used socketpair and fork. The child is managing the client / server Bluetooth connection and the parent does the graphics (OpenGL).  Works in principle, still haveing  some timing issues.